# Securing AJAX post to our API without ApiKey

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, authentication

We offer a web service, where a user can execute a POST request and get HTML. This is done server to server. The post that is sent with the request data includes his secret key, and other parameters.

We want to allow for this to be loaded via AJAX. So the request will be done client side, after the page has loaded. This way, no server side implementation will be required to install our service, beyond a slight modification to output the script.

We are not sure how to secure this operation, because we can not output the secret key as a JavaScript parameter (it is exposed that way). We usually use a user ID + apiKey combination to authenticate the request when it is don't server to server.

We know the users's key, and their valid domain, so if there's a way to make absolutely sure the domain that is sending the request cannot be faked, it may also solve our issue.

How can we make it so that we can differentiate requests coming that way, without exposing our secret key, so that we may provide the information only the authenticated requests?

Comment: `https` should be your protocol instead of `http` and this is not the whole solution but a bit.

Comment: _because we can not output the secret key as a JavaScript parameter (it is exposed that way)._ It is exposed anyway, even in the server-to-server case, unless you use secure connection (SSL/HTTPS).

Comment: We are using https anyhow, still not the solution :)

Comment: Then just send your data with `POST` AJAX request and  don't worry about exposure.

Comment: Don't worry about exposure? showing a user's ApiKey to everybody VIA the source code? It's like putting you login credentials.. Exactly what we are trying to avoid

Comment: I don't quite understand you. Do you output **fixed** (the same) ApiKey on webpage for all users?